# Return first element if no match found in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
    _id: 123,
    state: "AZ",
    products: [
        {
            product_id: 1,
            desc: "P1"
        },
        {
            product_id: 2,
            desc: "P2"
        }   
    ]
}
```

I need to write a query to return a single element from the products array where state is "AZ" and product_id is 2. If the matching product_id is not found, then return the first (or any) element from the products array.

For example: If product_id is 2 (match found), then the result should be:

```
products: [
    {
        product_id: 2,
        desc: "P2"
    }   
]
```

If the product_id is 3 (not found), then the result should be:

```
products: [
    {
        product_id: 1,
        desc: "P1"
    }   
]
```

I was able to meet one condition when the match is found but not sure how to satisfy the second condition in the same query:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"state": "AZ"}, {_id: 0, state: 0, products: { "$elemMatch": {"product_id": "2"}}})
```

I tried using the aggregation pipeline as well but could not find a working solution.

Note: This is different from the following question as I need to return a default element if the match is not found:
[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I need to return a default element in case the match is not found. This was not asked in the question you mentioned as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care which element you get back then this is the way to go (you'll get the last element in the array in case of no match since [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) will return -1):

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        "products": {
            $arrayElemAt: [ "$products", { $indexOfArray: [ "$products.product_id", 2 ] } ]
        },
    }
}])
```

If you want the first then do this instead ([$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) will take care of transforming -1 into index 0 which is the first element):

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        "products": {
            $arrayElemAt: [ "$products", { $max: [ 0, { $indexOfArray: [ "$products.product_id", 2 ] } ] } ]
        },
    }
}])
```

Here is a version that should work on v3.2 as well:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "products": {
            $slice: [{
                $concatArrays: [{
                    $filter: {
                        "input": "$products",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.product_id", 2] }
                    }},
                    "$products" // simply append the "products" array
                   // alternatively, you could append only the first or a specific item like this [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$products", 0 ] } ]
                ]
            },
            1 ] // take first element only
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks @dnickless, this would work on MongoDB 3.4 onwards only. Can we have a solution which would work on 3.2 as well? I would test it on 3.4+ as well but I need to solve this on 3.2 at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below aggregation

Basically you need to [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the `products` array and check for the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition if it doesn't contain any element or equal to **`[]`** then you have to [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) with the first element of the `products` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "products": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$eq": [
            { "$filter": {
              "input": "$products",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.product_id", 2] }
            }},
            []
          ]
        },
        { "$slice": ["$products", 1] },
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$products",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.product_id", 2] }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

or even using [**`$let`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "products": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "filt": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$products",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.product_id", 2] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$cond": [
            { "$eq": ["$$filt", []] },
            { "$slice": ["$products", 1] },
            "$$filt"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony. As this solution would only work on MongoDB 3.4 onwards, i was wondering if I simply change the $addFields to $project to make it work on v3.2 as I have access to 3.2 only. It didn't work using $project. I will test this on 3.4 and newer as well but wanted to see how this query can be written for older versions?

Comment: It will work if you use `$project` instead of `$addFields` because all the operators had been introduced in version 3.2. Here is the working example https://mongoplayground.net/p/BFD4CucD86t

Comment: Great, this works! Thanks for providing the working example.